# Found duplicate column when trying to query with Spark SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do a filter on a dataframe like so:

`filtered_df2 = filtered_df.select("li", "result.li", "fw").orderBy("fw")`

However, the nested column, `result.li` has the same name as `li` and this poses a problem. I get the following error:

`` AnalysisException: 'Found duplicate column(s) when inserting into hdfs://...: `li`;' ``

How can I filter both fields successfully ?

Comment: what do you mean by `filter` ? what do you expect as final result ? one column, or both column ?

Comment: Can you please add `filtered_df.printSchema()`

Comment: Sorry I think I've mispoke. What I want is to display all 3 columns separately when I show result. I filter the DF just one line before, but that was not a problem

Comment: I've got the solution now. What I needed to use was col().alias("something_else").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution now. What I needed to use was:

Add `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` at the file header

Simply use col()'s alias function like so:

`filtered_df2 = filtered_df.select(col("li"),col("result.li").alias("result_li"), col("fw")).orderBy("fw")`

Comment: don't do `import *` - if you do, you'll find that `sum`, `max`, `min`, etc have all been replaced by the spark functions.

Comment: Please mark this as answered, also for reference you can use "result.li" AS "result_li" too

Comment: I've tried the "AS" but did not work. I will mark as answered when I can , in two days

Comment: What @pault said. I like to have my import statement structures as `from pyspark.sql import functions as F ` and used that to refer to all contained functions. Ex: `F.col("result.li")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectExpr` and use `AS` to give column alias.

```
filtered_df2 = filtered_df\
    .selectExpr("li AS li", "result.li AS result_li", "fw AS  fw")\
    .orderBy("fw")
```